# how to create root user in vault

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I have created users in the vault with the root policy attached to it.

```
vault write auth/userpass/users/testuser password=testuser policies=root
```

When I try to login with user testuser it failed exception is authentication failed authpass cannot create root token

Answer (score 0):

There are only three ways to create `root` tokens due to the permissions that they have (ie everything).

More information [here](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/concepts/tokens.html#root-tokens) and the gist of it is:

1. `vault operator init`
2. By using another root token
3. `vault operator generate-root`

Comment: So it means that we cannot log in with the user (testuser in my case) who has the root policy attached to it. Right?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this on your vault/client server:

```
vault token create -format=json -policy="root" | jq -r ".auth.client_token"
```

Do not forget about the `$VAULT_TOKEN` and `$VAULT_ADDR` environment variables, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you can create the root token in 3 ways:-

1. **vault operator init**
2. By using root token (**vault token create -ttl=0**)(run this with root token)
3. **vault operator generate-root** (https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/generate-root)